# select all the items of a category four eloquent laravel

Tags: php, eloquent

as I can run this query in laravel 4 using eloquent?

```
SELECT article_category.alias, article.title FROM article_category INNER JOIN article ON article.category_id = article_category.id WHERE article_category.alias = 'news'
```

the route

```
articles/{category}
```

appreciate a hand, as I have hours thinking and succeeded with nail sar

Comment: and the question is ...

Comment: how to execute a query using eloquent? :S

Comment: If I understand the question, you're looking to select all the articles in the news category, using Eloquent?